# Changing font specification within \nicefrac

Tags: nicefrac

The package `\nicefrac` is a very useful tool for small fractions. In the documentation, it says that a font command optional argument can be given, but no example is provided. Specification:

```
\nicefrac[<fontcmd>]{<num>}{<denom>}
```

we only have a reference to `fntguide.dvi`. However, that guide is a bit cryptic.

Is it possible to have a few examples how `fontcmd` can be specified? Let's say I would want (a) a fraction using slightly bigger font; (b) a fraction using roman font numbers; (c) a fraction using bold numbers; (d) a fraction using something wild (to your appreciation ;-).

Comment: There are examples on page 3 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/units/units.pdf), e.g. `\nicefrac[\texttt]{1}{2}` or `$\nicefrac[\mathcal]{A}{B}$`

Comment: @mbert I saw those. I tried `\nicefrac[\LARGE]{a}{b}` but then alignments are wrong. I though with finer adjustments to the fontcmd, I would get properly aligned components.

Comment: Perhaps try `{\LARGE\nicefrac{a}{b}}`. However I think the result with [`xfrac`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xfrac.pdf) looks better: `{\LARGE\sfrac{a}{b}}`

Comment: @mbert thanks for the suggestions. However, it does not show how to use the fontcmd specification more generally.

Comment: I think in general the optional argument should just be a formatting command that takes one argument (like `\texttt` or `\mathcal`) and does not change the size, since making a size change there won't change the size of the solidus. Hence the size change before `\nicefrac`